# What is the best way to create icon from name?

Tags: flutter, icons

The icon to use is a name received from server side, e.g., "lock",

How to map "lock" to Icons.lock?

```
 Icon(Icons.lock)
```

Do I need to create a Map from string(name) to flutter icon constants? Expecting a static method

```
 Icons.fromName(String name)
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/material_design_icons_flutter and https://pub.dev/packages/string_2_icon use map inside

Comment: If you can instead have the server return a number instead of a string, e,g, `0xe3ae`, then you can use `IconData(0xe3ae, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')`.

Comment: Instantiating non-const instances of this class in your app will mean the app cannot be built in release mode with icon tree-shaking (it need to be explicitly opted out at build time). See [staticIconProvider] for more context. The icon number is an variable, so can not use const IconData(...). Is this a big issue or can be ignored?

Comment: @chunhunghan icons are not rendered using material_design_icons_flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173875/material-design-icons-flutter-no-icons-are-rendered-on-screen

Answer (score 2):

No need to maintain map, what you can do is,

Instead of

```
Icon(Icons.lock)
```

use

```
Icon(IconData(0xe3ae, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'))
```

Where `0xe3ae` needs to be passed from server, and it is `int`.

You can find code for each icon on `flutter/src/materials/icons.dart` .
You can navigate to that file by tapping on `Icon.icon_name` on your code.

Comment: Tree-shaking issue when creating IconData instances?

Comment: Creates icon data.

Rarely used directly. Instead, consider using one of the predefined icons like the [Icons] collection.

The [fontPackage] argument must be non-null when using a font family that is included in a package. This is used when selecting the font.

Instantiating non-const instances of this class in your app will mean the app cannot be built in release mode with icon tree-shaking (it need to be explicitly opted out at build time). See [staticIconProvider] for more context. From IconData doc.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how you can do :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Icon(IconMapper.fromName('lock')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IconMapper {
  static final _iconMap = <String, IconData>{
    'lock': Icons.lock,
    'alarm': Icons.alarm,
    'call': Icons.call,
    'camera_alt': Icons.camera_alt,
    // Add more icons as needed
  };

  static IconData fromName(String name) {
    return _iconMap[name] ??
        Icons.error; // Fallback to 'error' icon if name not found
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple `switch-case` method:

```
Icon displayIcon (nameOrIndex){
   switch (nameOrIndex) {
      case "lock":
         return Icon(Icons.lock);
   }
}
```