# material_design_icons_flutter: no icons are rendered on screen

Tags: flutter, material-icons

No icons are rendered on screen for icon names including:

```
person_add 
language 
schedule
dark_mode
```

material_design_icons_flutter: 7.0.7296

```
Icon(MdiIcons.fromString(iconName))
```

e.g.,

```
MenuItemButton(
  leadingIcon: Icon(MdiIcons.fromString('person_add')),
  child: Text('Click Me'),
);
```

Comment: person_add does not locationed in icon map. you can check source code here =>https://github.com/ziofat/material_design_icons_flutter/blob/master/lib/icon_map.dart

Comment: and languageC , languageCpp .... location in line 4066 https://github.com/ziofat/material_design_icons_flutter/blob/master/lib/icon_map.dart#L4066C4-L4066C13

Comment: many icon constants (defined in Icons class) are not found in the package icon map. Also naming does not follow the corresponding constant names. Is the package designed to provide name mappings for the flutter Icons class? Thanks

Comment: You can reference this Material Icons vs Material Design Icons https://uxplanet.org/material-icons-vs-material-design-icons-5a9410258d51